# Concise way to get indexes of array elements that are contained in another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays, `a` and `b`, e.g.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = [2,4];
```

I want to get the indexes of the elements of `a` that are contained in `b`. I could use a loop, like

```
var ii = [];
for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    if (y.indexOf(x[i]) >= 0)
        ii.push(i);
};
```

This works. But coming from the R language where this would simply be `which(a %in% b)`, I suppose there will be more concise ways to get what I want in JS. Suggestions? 
TIA :)

Comment: If you are already using any frameworks usually there will be a helper method bundled in to use. Otherwise, I think your function looks good!

Comment: I don't think there is more simple way. _R_ is specially designed for statistical calculations while Javascript is general purpose language without such specific functions.

Comment: There is not a more "concise" way in pure JavaScript (ie. there is no standard function or operator), but there are libraries that do support such.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it shorter by using `Array.map`

```
var idx = b.map(function(n){ return a.indexOf(n) }).filter(function(n){ 
    return n != -1
})
```

Comment: Have to filter out `-1`s

Comment: And now twice slower… :)

Answer (score 0):

There will always be some form of loop, either written outright or implied with a call to `Array.map()` or the like. There's not much of a way around that.

You shouldn't have to write that code, though. Libraries like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) and [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) have a method called [`intersection()`](https://lodash.com/docs#intersection) which does the bulk of this -- potentially with more than two arrays:

```
_.intersection([1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 4], [2, 1]);
// → [1, 2]
```

For the specific case of getting the indexes from `a`, you can chain the output of `intersection()` into `map()`:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = [2,4];

var result = _.intersection(a, b).map(function (v) {
    return a.indexOf(v);
});

console.log(result);
// → [1, 3]
```

Comment: Not exactly. PA want indexes, not values.

Answer (score 0):

Lodash also offers tools that could make this easy. If you fancy using external libraries:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = [2,4];

var intersection = _.intersection(a,b);

_.forEach(intersection, function(item){
    console.log(a.indexOf(item));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

But a pure vanilla solution could looks like:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = [2,4];

function intersection(a, b)
{
  var ai=0, bi=0;
  var result = new Array();

  while( ai < a.length && bi < b.length )
  {
     if      (a[ai] < b[bi] ){ ai++; }
     else if (a[ai] > b[bi] ){ bi++; }
     else /* they're equal */
     {
       result.push(a[ai]);
       ai++;
       bi++;
     }
  }

  return result;
}

var intersect = intersection(a,b);

intersect.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(a.indexOf(item));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = [2,4];

var idxs = b.reduce(function(l, r, idx) {
    var i = a.indexOf(r);
    return i > -1 ? (l.push(i), l) : l;
}, []);

console.log(idxs);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works by mapping array a to return its index or an empty string-

filtering the map for Numbers returns only the indexes.

But your original script is more efficient, which is worth a few bytes download.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var b = [2,4];

var a_in_b=a.map(function(itm,i){ return b.indexOf(itm)!=-1? i:''}).filter(Number);
```

/* a_in_b  value: (Array) [1,3]; */